# Netty as WebSocket server not starting in SpringBootTest

Tags: java, spring-boot, netty, spring-test, spring-websocket

I'm trying to write a simple WebSocket server app based on on Spring and Netty.

My application looks like this

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoReactiveWSApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoReactiveWSApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

with the following configuration

```
@Configuration
public class WebSocketConfig {

    @Bean
    public HandlerMapping handlerMapping() {
        final Map<String, WebSocketHandler> handlerMap = new HashMap<>();
        // will be populated later with routes and handlers

        SimpleUrlHandlerMapping mapping = new SimpleUrlHandlerMapping();
        mapping.setUrlMap(handlerMap);
        mapping.setOrder(-1);
        return mapping;
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestUpgradeStrategy requestUpgradeStrategy() {
        return new ReactorNettyRequestUpgradeStrategy();
    }
}
```

When I run it, everything boots up, and I can attempt (for now) to establish WS connection.

However, when I want to start it in a test

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class DemoReactiveWSAppTest {
    @LocalServerPort
    private String port;

    @Test
    public void givenContext_WhenStartingApplication_ThenItLoads() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Port: " + port);
    }
}
```

the server never seems to boot.

Am I forgetting something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid me, I forgot `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`